# GPUMLib unresolved externals at build time

Tags: visual-c++, cuda, cula

I am trying to build GPUMLib, and I get the following errors

```
Error   11  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl         GPUMLib::Random::SetSeed(unsigned __int64,enum curandRngType)" (?SetSeed@Random@GPUMLib@@SAX_KW4curandRngType@@@Z) referenced in function _main  C:\libraries\GPUMLib1\build\src\examples\DBN\DBNapp.obj

Error   12  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl GPUMLib::Random::Fill(class GPUMLib::DeviceArray<float> &)" (?Fill@Random@GPUMLib@@SAXAAV?$DeviceArray@M@2@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall GPUMLib::RBM::ContrastiveDivergence(int)" (?ContrastiveDivergence@RBM@GPUMLib@@QAEXH@Z)   C:\libraries\GPUMLib1\build\src\examples\DBN\RBMKernels.lib(RBMKernels_generated_rbm.cu.obj)
Error   13  error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals   C:\libraries\GPUMLib1\build\src\examples\DBN\Debug\DBN.exe  1
```

Any ideas what might be causing this ? Please note that this is the only part that is unsuccessfully built from the entire library

```
20>  Build all projects
21>------ Skipped Build: Project: INSTALL, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
21>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
========== Build: 19 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 1 skipped ==========
```

Comment: This sounds like a question for the authors of the code you are compiling, not a CUDA or CULA programming question on [SO].

Comment: In order to get most of the library built so far I had to insert #define CULA_USE_CUDA_COMPLEX before every CULA include. Strangely enough, I think this part of the library build was working prior to these adjustments. I am no expert on this but it would be nice to get this library up and running.

Comment: @valentin Try posting on the GPUMlib or CULA forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the authors of the library suggested, in the src/random folder I had to rename "random.cu" to "random.cpp". This solved the problem.